# CMD equivalent of cat >> text.txt

Tags: windows, unix, cmd.exe, cat

type >> text.txt doesn't work on Windows. I want it to prompt me to enter text into the document and then allow me to finish by entering control + d.

Comment: you can type directly to a file with "copy con text.txt" <enter>  then proceed  to type whatever you like. Close the file with ;ctrl-c' .  There is no prompt, after you hit enter just start typing. To print a file on the screen type "copy text.txt con" <enter>

Comment: @Larryc IIRC it [ctrl]+[Z] or [F6], then [ENTER] to properly terminate the input.

Comment: No, in Linux its ctrl-d, in msdos its ctrl-c.

Comment: @Larryc ctrl-c cancels the creation of the file [see this ref](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/copycon.htm)  (the line currently entered line is discarded) while ctrl-z inserts an EOF (end of file) marker.

Comment: Ah! that's probably why I learned to enter a blank line before closing. The EOF marker doesn't actually close the file, you have to follow up with the enter key, but it gets the job done. I haven't really used this for a long time, back when edlin was the editor. Interesting that unix guys are still relying on these old forms of editing. I can still use Vi or Emacs like riding a bicycle, but it just isn't needed much these days. Thanks for the reminder.